# Why does alert box not run?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that I am trying to run

```
const greeting = () => {
    alert(`Hello ${name}`)
}

greeting();
```

It runs without any error

But when the variable name inside the function is anything other than the word `name`

```
const greeting = () => {
    alert(`Hello ${someOtherWord}`)
}

greeting();
```

This throws an error? Why does this happen?

Here is the **error**:

`reference error: someOtherWord is not defined`

Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Is `someOtherWord` defined in the scope containing the definition of `greeting()`?

Comment: `name` is defined as a property of the `window` so it will exist without you needing to define it, unlike `someOtherWord`

Comment: `name` is a "type protected" property of `window`, it's always a string, and accessible in the global scope. You haven't defined other variables used inside the expression, that's why they trigger an error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: You should be curious about the first example as why it is working instead of worrying about the second why that is not working.

Comment: @danh No is it not defined. So it is throwing the error. But even name is not defined in the scope. The same works without any error.

Comment: name is defined, per @NickParsons comment

Comment: btw, this isn't just limited to `name`, you can see some of the properties which this works for by running: `for(const prop in window) console.log(prop)`, there are more though.

Answer (score 2):

As some of the comments have mentioned, when this code gets run in a browser environment, the variable `name` will always exist.
The reason for this is that, within the browser, your *Global Scope* is the `window` object. This means that any properties on the `window` object can be called directly by their property name, without explicitly calling `window.somePropertyName`. One of these default `window` object properties is `window.name`, which is what you're actually referencing when you call `name` inside of your alert, and thus why you don't throw an error, because it's always defined.

Conversely, `someOtherWord` in this case does not exist, at least not in the code you've shared here. For the variable name `someOtherWord` to be accessible within `greeting` it needs to be declared and assigned either within the scope of your function, or within a scope that encloses your function, which in this case is the global scope.

Two working examples:

```js
const enclosedGreeting = () => {
  const someOtherWord = 'This is an alert!';
  alert(`Hello ${someOtherWord}`);
}

const someOtherWord = 'This is an alert!';

const globalGreeting= () => {
  alert(`Hello ${someOtherWord}`);
}

enclosedGreeting();
globalGreeting();
```

You can copy and paste this entire code block into your runtime environment and it will run without any undefined OR namespace collision errors, because the first declaration of `someOtherWord` inside `enclosedGreeting()` only exists within the curly braces which define that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should first declare another variable and it should be in the scope as well. Something like:

```
let someOtherWord = "hello World";
const greeting = () => {
    alert(`Hello ${someOtherWord}`)
}

greeting();
```

Answer (score 0):

So `name` is a special word of the browser window and is universally accessible in all scripts. But in case of you typing `someOtherWord` its being taken as a variable and causes an error as you have not declared the variable.

So if you just want to alert any word remove the $ and {} like this:

```js
const greeting = () => {
    alert(`Hello someOtherWord`)
}

greeting();
```

But if you want use anything dynamic then you can use a variable like this:

```js
const greeting = (message) => {
    alert(`Hello ${message}`)
}

greeting("John");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not declared it. As the earlier post says that it is not declared. `name` must've been already declared in your code. Other things are not. Thus you must first actually *declare* it. Then it will be alerted.